# Mocking in Unit Tests with Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am trying to set up a simple mocking example, taken from this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1635):

```
'use strict';

var expect = chai.expect;

var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
    .factory('car', function(engine) {
        return {
            drive : function() {
                return 'Driving: ' + engine.speed();
            }
        }
    })
    .value('engine', {
        speed : function() {
            return 'fast';
        }
    });

describe('Testing a car', function() {
    var testEngine;

    beforeEach(function(){
        testEngine = {};
        angular.module('test', ['plunker']).value('engine', testEngine);
        module('test');
    });

    it('should drive slow with a slow engine', inject(function(car) {
        testEngine.speed = function() {
            return 'slow';
        };
        expect(car.drive()).to.equal('Driving: slow');
    }));
});
```

However, when I try to run it with Testacular (using Mocha), I get the following error:

```
info (watcher): Changed file "/path/to/testMock.js".
PhantomJS 1.7 (Mac) Testing a car "before each" hook FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.queue.running')
        at isSpecRunning (/path/to/angular-mocks.js:1626)
        at /path/to/angular-mocks.js:1648
        at /path/to/testMock.js:25
PhantomJS 1.7 (Mac): Executed 29 of 41 (1 FAILED) (0.215 secs / NaN secs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK mocks for mocha are not available in the stable release of angular. They have been added to the unstable 1.1.1 release. code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/angular-mocks.js.